# Customer Pole Display Text Horizontal Scroll Continuously C#

Tags: c#, macros, serial-port, hex

I have now figured out how to make the text scroll horizontally as below

```
byte[] byteScrollMSGHorizontal = new byte[2] { 0x1F, 0x03 };
port.Write(byteScrollMSGHorizontal, 0, byteScrollMSGHorizontal.Length);

char[] Msg = " *HELLO WORLD* ".ToCharArray();
               for (int i = 0; i < Msg.Length; i++)
               {


                       port.Write(Msg[i].ToString());
                       Thread.Sleep(110);

               }
```

But it only scrolls until the end of the Msg. I want the text to be scrolling Continuously. I guess using macro is the way but couldn't figure out.
Below attached is the pictures of the HEX CODES for the Customer Pole Display VFD-850. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try making a message that is longer the the number of characters in the width of the display.  The display is 20x20 characters.  Your message is only 15 character.  So you do not see scrolling unless your message is more the 20 characters.

Comment: Where is the EOT, SOH, and ETB?  With code posted the device may not be getting the scroll command.  I also not sure if you may need to set window size ESC W when message is less than 20 characters.  Scrolling should not require a macro.

Comment: @jdweng i have tried text longer than 20 char, let say 25 character, it just scrolls to the 25th character and stops

Answer (score 1):

```
public void  comtest ()
        {
            SerialPort sport = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sport.Open();
            string Msg = "*HELLO WORLD*";
            string ogstring = Msg + " ";
            string mystring = "";
            string displaystring = "";
            for (int count = 0; count <= Msg.Length; count++)
            {
                if (mystring == "")
                {
                    mystring = ogstring;
                }
                if (mystring.Length > 20)
                {
                    displaystring = mystring.Substring(0, 20);
                }
                else
                {
                    displaystring = mystring;
                }
                sport.Write(new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x0D }, 0, 2);
                sport.Write(displaystring);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                string s = mystring[0].ToString();
                mystring = mystring.Substring(1);
                mystring = mystring + s;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code does and how it answers the question?

Comment: Here removing the first character from custom string and adding the removed character to the end position of same custom string , same process repleted for each character in custom string  and write command passed to com port with  in every loop hence it makes  a horizontal scrolling effect

Comment: OK, thanks for adding information as a comment. However, this is not the recommended way to add information, instead, please edit the explanation into your answer. Thanks.